# Дважды выполняется метод close (FileInputStre

Tags: java, java-output-stream

```
public class AmigoOutputStream extends FileOutputStream {
public static String fileName = "D:/tmp/result.txt";
private FileOutputStream original = null;


public AmigoOutputStream(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) throws Exception {
    super(fileOutputStream.getFD());
    this.original = fileOutputStream;
}

@Override
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    original.write(b);
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    original.write(b);
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    original.write(b, off, len);
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    original.flush();
    original.write("JavaRush © All rights reserved.".getBytes());
    original.close();
}

@Override
public void flush() throws IOException {
    original.flush();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AmigoOutputStream amigoOutputStream = new AmigoOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    amigoOutputStream.close();
}
```

Это содержание выходного файла:

```
JavaRush © All rights reserved.JavaRush © All rights reserved.
```

Похоже, метод close выполняется дважды, проверено отладчиком. 
Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы слишком усложнили решение, не уверен в чем же конкретно было дело, но по крайней мере так оно работает как надо:

```
public class AmigoOutputStream extends FileOutputStream {

    public AmigoOutputStream(String fileName) throws Exception {
        super(fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.write("JavaRush © All rights reserved.".getBytes());
        super.flush();
        super.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AmigoOutputStream amigoOutputStream = new AmigoOutputStream("result.txt");
        amigoOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но дело, в общем то, не в решении. Да хорошо вызываем super(filname) и радуемся жизни, согласен. А теперь рассмотрим ситуацию, если у нас нет доступа к filename и нам в какой либо метод приходит готовый объект fileOutputStream. Как создать такой же объект? Я вижу единственный способ - это передать в конструктор FileDescriptor (его возвращает getFD) но тогда close будет выполняться два раза.... поэтому вопрос остается открытым...

Comment: Смысл вообще в чем? Чтоб при закрытии строку одну дописывать?